# Cant discover bluetooth services from peripheral

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

Building an app to connect to an Arduino bluetooth module, finds the devices fine but when it comes to discovering services its always nil.
Im fine up to the discover services function which I don't really understand

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class Devices: UITableViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

    var devices = [String]()
    var centralManager : CBCentralManager!
    var peripheral: CBPeripheral!
    var central: CBCentralManager!
    var peripheralArray: [CBPeripheral] = []
    var service : CBService!

    var deviceConnected = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        self.refreshControl!.addTarget(self, action: "scanForDevices:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        central = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn {
            print("Bluetooth On")
        }
        else {
            print("Bluetooth off or not supported")
        }
    }


    func scanForDevices(sender: AnyObject) {

        devices.removeAll()
        print("Scanning")
        central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (Int64)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.central.stopScan()
            self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
            print("Stopped Scanning")
        }


    }

    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {


        (advertisementData as NSDictionary).objectForKey(CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey) as? NSString

        let list = String(peripheral.name!)

        if (devices.contains(list)){
        } else {devices.append(list)
            peripheralArray.append(peripheral)

        }

        tableView.reloadData()


    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return devices.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("device")! as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = devices[indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        if(deviceConnected == false){
            self.central.connectPeripheral(peripheralArray[indexPath.row], options: nil)

            deviceConnected = true
        }else{
            self.central.cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheralArray[indexPath.row])
            deviceConnected = false
        }

        discoverServices()

        self.peripheral = peripheralArray[indexPath.row]
        print(self.peripheral.services)



    }


    func discoverServices(){



        for service in peripheral.services! {
            let thisService = service as? CBService
                if let thisService = thisService{
                    peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, forService: thisService)
            }
        }
    }




    }
```

Comment: Don't call `discoverServices` until you get confirmation that you are connected to the peripheral via the `didConnectPeripheral` delegate method

Answer (score 0):

You are going straight to characteristic discovery without discovering services first. Before you call `discoverCharacteristics` you need to call `discoverServices`. Once the services have been discovered, the `peripheral:didDiscoverServices:` delegate method will be called and you can use this to trigger characteristic discovery.

For the `discoverServices` call, you can either pass it an array of the `CBUUID` addresses you want to discover (recommended) or, if you don't know which services you want, you can pass it `nil` to discover all services it has.

Comment: I have tried `print(peripheralArray[0].services)` and the results are still nil?